# How to determine if an object has fallen down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing an application using `Unity`.

I wrote the following code to determine if a pin　object like the one below has fallen down.
But, in this case, even if the pin object falls down, it sometimes does not return `true`.

How could I edit the code to make sure that an object has fallen down?

[image]

---

Here is the code:

```
   bool CheckFallenDown(Transform transform) {
        if (transform.rotation.x * transform.rotation.x > 0.01f && transform.rotation.z * transform.rotation.z > 0.01f) {
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

---

Unity 2020.3.16f

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the `return false` line and watch the `transform.rotation` values?

Comment: @Sergey I haven't tried that method

Comment: "collapsed" is not really the phrase for a fallen pin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I guess is actually to simply compare the pin's [`transform.up`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-up.html) vector to the world's global [`Vector3.up`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-up.html) using [`Vector3.Angle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) like e.g.

```
private const float THRESHOLD = 0.01f;

public bool CheckCollpse(Transform transform)
{
    return Vector3.Angle(transform.up, Vector3.up) > THRESHOLD;
}
```